# How do I use async_start and async_stop in systrace/atrace for Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, trace, systrace, ftrace

I want to capture Systrace report on my Android phone while doing automated testing. It is unknown how long the testing will take, so I can't specify the *--time* period for the Systrace.

Digging deeper in to the *systrace.py*, I found out that *systrace* is using *atrace* to get the kernel logs.

I used `adb shell atrace --help` and got the following output:

```
usage: atrace [options] [categories...]
options include:
  -a appname      enable app-level tracing for a comma separated list of cmdlines
  -b N            use a trace buffer size of N KB
  -c              trace into a circular buffer
  -k fname,...    trace the listed kernel functions
  -n              ignore signals
  -s N            sleep for N seconds before tracing [default 0]
  -t N            trace for N seconds [defualt 5]
  -z              compress the trace dump
  --async_start   start circular trace and return immediatly
  --async_dump    dump the current contents of circular trace buffer
  --async_stop    stop tracing and dump the current contents of circular
                    trace buffer
  --list_categories
                  list the available tracing categories
```

How can I use *atrace* to start tracing at the beginning of my automated testing, and stop the tracing and dumping the kernel log at the end of my automated testing?

I tried using the following commands, but I don't think it works properly. Only async_dump gives me some data in the log. async_stop dump doesn't have any content in the log. How do I properly start the trace, dump it, and then stop it?

```
adb shell atrace -b 10000 -c am shedgfx view --async_start > C:\Users\user1\Desktop\log.txt 

adb shell atrace -b 10000 -c am shedgfx view --async_dump  > C:\Users\user1\Desktop\log.txt 

adb shell atrace -b 10000 -c am shedgfx view --async_stop > C:\Users\user1\Desktop\log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `schedgfx` should probably be 2 separate calls:  `sched` and `gfx`. See the output from your device when running:

   `$ adb shell atrace --list_categories`
2. The categories should be the **last** part of the command line (in your commands, the categories are placed before the `async_*` options):

   `$ adb shell atrace --help
   usage: atrace [options] [categories...]
   options include:
   -a appname      enable app-level tracing for a comma separated list of cmdlines
   -b N            use a trace buffer size of N KB
   -c              trace into a circular buffer
   -k fname,...    trace the listed kernel functions
   -n              ignore signals
   -s N            sleep for N seconds before tracing [default 0]
   -t N            trace for N seconds [defualt 5]
   -z              compress the trace dump
   --async_start   start circular trace and return immediatly
   --async_dump    dump the current contents of circular trace buffer
   --async_stop    stop tracing and dump the current contents of circular
                   trace buffer
   --list_categories
                 list the available tracing categories`
3. The tool runs on a circular buffer, so each time you run the dump command, you'll only get whatever contents are in the buffer at that time.  In the Espresso `rules:0.5` package (assuming you are using Espresso), there is an `AtraceLogger` class that can help automate this for you as part of your test harness, by calling the `atraceStart(...)` method:

   `public void atraceStart(Set<String> traceCategoriesSet, int atraceBufferSize, int dumpIntervalSecs, File destDirectory, String traceFileName) throws IOException`

   You can do that by creating a @Rule or @ClassRule, or hook into it some other way such as with a TestRunner:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void before() throws Throwable {
       mAtrace = AtraceLogger.getAtraceLoggerInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
       mAtrace.atraceStart(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("gfx", "sched", ...)),
               1024 /* bufferSize */, 1 /* dump interval */,
               RuleLoggingUtils.getTestRunDir(), "filename");
   }

   @Override
   protected void after() {
       try {
           mAtrace.atraceStop();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.w(TAG, "Failed to stop Atrace", e);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           Log.w(TAG, "Failed to stop Atrace", e);
       }
   }
   ```

   The `RuleLoggingUtils.getTestRunDir()` method will place the captured dump files into the external files path for your app, so you can pull those files after the test is finished, using:

   `$ adb pull /sdcard/Android/data/com.yourcompany.package/files/testdata/`

And each atrace file can then be inspected using the systrace viewer by running systrace with the `--from-file=<trace file>` option.