# How do I prevent task/process name from being trimmed in Systrace or atrace kernel log output?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, strace, systrace, ftrace

How do I ensure the task name/process name in kernel log outputs from Systrace/atrace don't get trimmed or cut off? I want to see the whole name of the task/process name without it get shortened.

Below is an example of Systrace output without the task name/process name being trimmed:

```
com.google.android.youtube-15500 (-----) [002] ...1 45565.756759: tracing_mark_write: B|15500|activityPause\n\
com.google.android.youtube-15500 (-----) [002] ...1 45565.764622: tracing_mark_write: E\n\
com.google.process.gapps-2028  (-----) [003] ...1 45572.446779: tracing_mark_write: B|2028|serviceStop\n\
com.google.process.gapps-2028  (-----) [003] ...1 45572.446876: tracing_mark_write: E\n\
```

Below is the Systrace/atrace output where the task name/process name get trimmed:

```
 android.youtube-28439 (28439) [003] ...1 18976.475357: tracing_mark_write: B|28439|serviceBind
 android.youtube-28439 (28439) [001] ...1 18976.475896: tracing_mark_write: E
 e.process.gapps-20011 (20011) [003] ...1 18976.490724: tracing_mark_write: B|20011|serviceCreate
 e.process.gapps-20011 (20011) [003] ...1 18976.490968: tracing_mark_write: E
```

I have tested using Systrace/atrace on multiple computers: Windows and Linux. With exception of a latest updated Ubuntu Linux computer, all other computers give a Systrace output where the task/process names get trimmed. However, all the computers give me atrace report that has the trimmed task/process names.

**How do I ensure the task/process names are NOT getting trimmed?**

**Background**

I am using two methods to pull kernel logs on Android 5.1 phone: Systrace and atrace. I am using atrace because it's my understanding that Systrace is just a python front end to atrace. Another reason why I am using atrace is because I am [trying to get async tracing start and stop of the tracing working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192104/how-do-i-use-async-start-and-async-stop-in-systrace-atrace-for-android).

Command when using Systrace:

```
python systrace.py -t 10 -o trace.html gfx am shed
```

Command when using atrace:

```
adb shell atrace -t 10 gfx am shed > trace.txt
```

Comment: It's using the thread name set by `prctl(PR_SET_NAME)`, which only has room for 16 bytes (including the terminating null).

Comment: @fadden Sorry I am a noob. What does this mean? How can I increase the 16 bytes limit? Why is it that Systrace on only one computer gives me non-trimmed output while everywhere else I get trimmed output?